# How can I recursively add only unique items from one list to another?

Tags: python, recursion

I've been trying to recursively add unique items from one list to another, but I only get the first value. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
def bag_to_set(bag):
    new_set = []
    if len(bag) > 0:
        if bag[0] not in new_set:
            new_set.append(bag[0]) 
        bag = bag[1:]
        bag = bag_to_set(bag)

    return new_set
```

Comment: Each recursive call defines its own ***local*** `new_set`. The one that is returned eventually is the first one where you added `bag[0]` to....

Answer (score 0):

using recursion

```
def bag_to_set(array, unique=None):
    if unique is None:
        unique = set()
    if not array:
        return unique
    val = array.pop()
    unique.add(val)
    
    return bag_to_set(array, unique)
 
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,12,3,4,5,6]
print(bag_to_set(array))
# output -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(arr):
    #recurisve function taking index as argument
    def helper(ind):
        #when we reach last index return the result
        if ind==len(arr)-1:
            return res.copy()

        #check for duplicates and append item if its starting index
        if arr[ind]!=arr[ind-1] or ind==0:
            res.append(arr[ind])
            helper(ind+1)

    return helper(0)# calling helper function with starting index 0
    
res=[]
arr=[1,2,3,3]
fun(arr)
print(res)
```

Here, we recursively call the defined helper function which checks if there is duplicate element and add the item in the result list accordingly.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This gives the correct results and is in the spirit of the recursive approach I think you are driving at:

```
def bag_to_set(bag):
    if not bag:
        return []
    new_set = bag_to_set(bag[:-1])
    if bag[-1] not in new_set:
        new_set.append(bag[-1]) 
    return new_set
```

Some example cases:

```
print(bag_to_set([]))
print(bag_to_set([2]))
print(bag_to_set([2, 2]))
print(bag_to_set([2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 10]))
print(bag_to_set([10, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3]))
```

which prints:

```
[]
[2]
[2]
[2, 3, 5, 10]
[10, 5, 3, 2]
```

Note that if you impose the requirements that (a) the function returns a list, and (b) it operates recursively, then you end up having to check `not in` against a list, which is O(N), whereas for a set it would be O(1). So the recursive process as a whole will be O(N**2), when non-recursive O(N) approaches exist.